# How to check in shell script if output of command contains a specific word?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Sometimes I have network connectivity issues and I need to re-run the previous command. Not sure how to for the if else statement though?

```
for var in ./*
do python2.7 submit.py $var
//check if output of previous do statement has word traceback
 if    
   python2.7 submit.py $var
 else
   //if it does not contain word traceback continue with the for loop
   continue??
done
```

Comment: There is no "previous `do` statement"; the `do ... done` form a block specifying the commands that are repeated by the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the program output for anything else, I would do it like this:

```
for var in ./*
do
  while ! python2.7 submit.py "$var" | grep -qFe traceback
  do
    echo "Trying again for $var ..."
  done
  echo "Succeeded for $var."
done
```

If the program output is small, it may be better to redirect it into a variable and check that (because it saves one fork+exec per iteration):

```
for var in ./*
do
  while [[ "$(python2.7 submit.py "$var")" != *traceback* ]]
  do
    echo "Trying again for $var ..."
  done
  echo "Succeeded for $var."
done
```

Comment: `while [[ "$(python2.7 submit.py "$var")" != *traceback* ]]; do :; done` would work too.

Comment: Trying to understand the above code posted. Where would I put these 2 lines in the above code: 

 echo "$var was uploaded successfully will now upload the next file" 

and 

 echo $var failed to upload, will now try to upload $var again"

Comment: how do you format code inside comments?

Comment: See my edit and http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting.

Comment: there is something wrong with the above code: `for var in ./libreoffice4.1/*; do while [[ "$(python2.7 avsubmit.py -f $var -j)" != *traceback* ]]; do echo "Trying again for $var ..."; done; echo "Succeeded for $var."; done` but this (without the while loop): `for var in ./libreoffice4.1/*; do python2.7 avsubmit.py -f $var -j; done` works

Comment: Can you clarify, please? What do you expect to happen and what does happen instead?